# Concatenate RGB channels with a loop 'for'

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have R,G,B image channels of an image and I want to concatenate them to get the colored image using a `for` loop. Is it possible?

I tried something like below but it gives me an error:

```
for i=1:3
   image=cat(3,img(:,:,i)
end
```

I already know how to do it without a loop using the command `cat` : `image=cat(3,imgR,imgG,imgB)`

Comment: I don't see any practical possibility to use a for loop. What is wrong with the solution you already have?

Comment: Well, it gives you an error because you don't have enough close parentheses, but you've also got a logic error because you're just overwriting `image` each time.

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop?

Comment: I'm working on color image watermarking, and I watermark every color channel so instead of using 3 functions  with the same process to each channel, I use a loop to apply the same one function and then I want to concatenate them to get my color image watermarked

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a point in using a loop here... it's very inefficient... especially if you know how many images you want to stack together.  The call to `cat` as you have alluded to in your post at the very end is more than sufficient.

however, if you want to get this working, you have to specify **at least two matrices** that you want to use to concatenate together to create a new matrix when using `cat` in order to perform concatenation.  You are only specifying one matrix and if you do this, the output will simply be just the channel itself and if you use this code, you will only extract out the blue channel (the last channel).

If you want to retain the concatenations made for each channel, do this instead:

```
for ii = 1 : 3
    image = cat(3, image, img(:,:,ii));
end
```

This will take the pre-existing variable `image` and concatenate your matrix with each slice in `img` and update the variable `image`.